# If statement to tell if a file is in a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I am writing a bash script and want it to tell me if the names of the files in a directory appear in a text file and if not, remove them.

Something like this:

```
counter = 1
numFiles = ls -1 TestDir/ | wc -l 
while [$counter -lt $numFiles]
do
     if [file in TestDir/ not in fileNames.txt]
     then
          rm file
     fi
     ((counter++))
done
```

Comment: Variable assignments should not have any spaces around the `=` sign: `counter=1` e.g. Also the values should be quoted if they contain spaces: `foo="bar baz"`. To assign the output of a command to a variable, you need command substitution syntax: `numFiles=$(ls -1 TestDir/ | wc -l)`.

Comment: got the best answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320683/how-to-remove-files-from-a-directory-if-their-names-are-not-in-a-text-file-bash/49321118#49321118

Comment: The best answer according to you...

Comment: @J.Tate that answer is dangerous (the `-f` is risky) and will fail if your file names can be substrings of one another. So, if you have a file called `fo` in your list, that command will deleted `afore`, `foobar`, `yolofoyo` etc etc. Also, if the file list can't be read for whatever reason, that command will delete every file in the directory. I'm afraid it really isn't a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than saving the file list in a variable, loop over the names:

```bash
for name in TestDir/*; do
    # the rest of the code
done
```

To test whether `$name` occurs in the `fileNames.txt`, use `grep -q`:

```bash
for name in TestDir/*; do
    if ! grep -qxF "$name" fileNames.txt; then
        echo rm "$name"
    fi
done
```

The `-F` makes `grep` perform a string comparison rather than a regular expression match.  With `-q` we get no output from `grep`, just an exit status that we can use with the `if` statement (true if the string was found but the exclamation mark inverts the sense of the test).  The `-x` tells `grep` that the string `$name` needs to match a whole line, from start to finish, not just a part of a line.

I have protected the actual `rm` with `echo`.  Run and make sure that the correct files gets deleted.

If the filenames are listed without the `TestDir` path, then change `$name` in the `grep` command to `${name##*/}`:

```bash
for name in TestDir/*; do
    if ! grep -qxF "${name##*/}" fileNames.txt; then
        echo rm "$name"
    fi
done
```

This will look for the filename portion of the path in `$name` rather than the full path including `TestDir`.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
expected=(${(f)"$(<fileNames.txt)"}) || exit
cd TestDir || exit
actual=(*(D))
superfluous=(${actual:|expected})
if (($#superfluous)) {
  echo These files are not in the expected list:
  printf ' - %q\n' $superfluous
  read -q '?Do you want to delete them? ' && rm -rf -- $superfluous
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working version using your approach:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
fileList="$1"
targetDir="$2"

## Read the list of files into an associative array
declare -A filesInFile
while IFS= read -r file; do
  filesInFile["$file"]=1
done < "$fileList"

## Collect the files in the target dir
filesInDir=("$targetDir"/*);

for file in "${filesInDir[@]}"; do
  file=${file##*/}; # get the name of the file; remove path
  ## If this file has no entry in the array, delete
  if [[ -z "${filesInFile[$file]}" ]]; then
      echo "rm $file"
  fi
done
```

Remove the `echo` to actually delete the files. Note that I am not checking if the number of files differs, since there didn't seem much point given that the number of files might be the same but you could still have files whose name isn't in the list.